# HTTP get request works only one time with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to access REST API using ionic.

```
updateMachine(id) {
  console.log(id);
  if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
    });
  });
}
```

This is the promise of the service. When I click a button it triggers the function which calls to the above service. But request sends only 1st-time ionic app loads. after that, it doesn't send the request to the server. but send the response which fetched 1st time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the code is written to work, the logic is

> if data is not set, then query data from http, other wise return existing data

this part checks the existing data and returns existing data and your fuction is not going further to do another http call

```
if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }
```